# Api route returning empty array

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.4

Api route returning empty array evenif table contains data.
I want to list the users.Route model binding fails

This is my api route

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/users',function(){
    return App\User::get();
});
```

This is my vue component used in the blade template

```
    <template>
        <div class="row" style="min-height:250px;">
            <ul>
                <li v-for="user in users">

                    @{{user.name}}

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default{
        data() {
            return {
                    users : [],
                }
        },
        ready: function(){
            this.getUsers();
        },
        methods: {
            getUsers: function(response){
                axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/users')
                    .then(response => {
                        this.users = response.data;
                     })
                    .catch(error =>  {

                    });             
                },
        },
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: It was my mistake. ready is deprecated in vuejs 2, instead mounted is used

Comment: I don't get it. That axios.get works for you without getting any 401 (unauthorized) response ?